# Nodejs npm update status output

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process

Using the following code to get the stdout data from the "npm update" child process:

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('npm update');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("data :"+data.toString());
}
```

Getting only the final messages from the process:

[image]

Want to get info messages that appear during the update:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got a possible answer, the information that is shown during the npm execution corresponds to the verbose log level output, so if we set the loglevel to verbose (default is 'warn') we will get the verbose output to stderr wich is the default stream as stated in the documentation.
The following solved my problem:

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('npm update --loglevel="verbose"');

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        logger.info("npm update status:", data.toString());
    });
```